# Highlighting python stack traces

Tags: python, debugging, bash

I'm working on quite complex project and time after time I have to narrow down problems looking at stack traces. They happen to be very long and involve “my” code, standard library code and 3rd party libraries code at same time. Most of time the real problem is in “my” code and locating it instantly in a stack trace is a bit hard for eyes. Under “my” code I mean the code that is under current working directory.

So I realized that I want something that will colorize stack traces and highlight lines that are mine. Compare [original](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1729997/stack-trace/bw.png) to [highlighted](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1729997/stack-trace/hl.png).

I could write a python script that I could use this way:

```
nosetests | colorize_stack_trace.py
```

But I believe there is a quicker and more elegant way to do this using Linux toolset. Any ideas?

**UPD:**

Using supercat suggested by Dennis Williamson, the intermediate result is following bash function:

```
pyst() {
    rc=/tmp/spcrc;
    echo '#################### ### # # # ########################################' > $rc;
    echo '                     blk   0 r ^(.*)$' >> $rc;
    echo '                     mag b 0 r ^\s*File "'`pwd`'/(.*)"' >> $rc;
    spc -c $rc;
}
```

Now I can do:

```
nosetests 2>&1 | pyst
```

Not too elegant, but works at some degree. There are two problems left:

1. I can't see any output before nosetests completes. I.e. I don't see the progress.
2. I have to write 2>&1 over and over again.

**UPD 2:**

Asking this question I had mainly `nosetests` in mind. And I just found great solution: [rednose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rednose/0.1.4) nose plugin. It highlights paths that are local plus do many more handy readability things.

Returning to original question: problems that I noted with supercat don't relate to it completely but its a problem of Unix shell streaming, flushing, piping, redirecting. So as as an answer to the question *asked* I accept an answer that suggests supercat.

Comment: rednose is nice. You can have it enabled by default by adding `rednose=1` to your `.noserc`

Comment: Please update this question to fix the pair of deadlinks in "Compare original to highlighted."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/index.html) (spc). It does both ANSI and HTML highlighting and can be configured for your particular output. It comes with some configuration files for source code files in C and Python, for example and log files, Changelogs, diffs and others.

Based on **Dave Kirby's** suggestion for vim, this does something similar:

```
less -p regex file_name
```

Or

```
some_command | less -p regex
```

Answer (score 28):

Actually, there is a great Python syntax highlighting library called [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), which is also able to highlight  tracebacks.

So, all you have to do is:

```
$ easy_install pygments # downloads and installs pygments
$ cat traceback.txt | pygmentize -l pytb
```

"pytb" is the shortcut for the PythonTracebackLexer. There is also a special lexer for Python 3 Tracebacks included, which is called "py3tb".

You can format the output in various formats (including html, latex, svg, several image formats and so on). But there is also a terminal formatter available (and if you are wondering... of course there are different color themes available!).

You can use `-f html` to select another formatter (in that case, the HTML formatter).

Comment: Is there any way for python to colorize tracebacks magically, without piping anything to any other tool?

Answer (score 7):

There is a nice module just for that purpose:

- [colored-traceback @ github](https://github.com/staticshock/colored-traceback.py)
- [colored-traceback @ pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colored-traceback/)

You just have to download and install it via pip:

```
pip install colored-traceback
```

Import it into a top-level file of your project, for exmaple like this:

```
if DEBUG:
    import colored_traceback
    colored_traceback.add_hook()
```

And you get a traceback like that for every underling file (colors vary):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./workflowy.py", line 525, in <module>
    main()
  File "./workflowy.py", line 37, in main
    projects = cli.load_json(args, input_is_pipe)
  File "./workflowy.py", line 153, in load_json
    return json.load(sys.stdin)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: You can even get it down to one line by doing `import colored_traceback.auto` (which is the same as doing the import and `add_hook()` call on separate lines)

Comment: Note also that `coloured-traceback` has been out of development since 2017

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the [cgitb](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/cgitb/) module (short official doc [here](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html)) as a starting point (it creates nice HTML tracebacks). It should be relatively simple to make the modifications you need (e.g. add a color tag according to the file path). But of course this is only viable if you are willing to use the browser to view the traces.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but its a bit strange to use browser for viewing test results. Smells like action script and QUnit. Not as flexible as it can be :)

Comment: @nailxx You might want to look at this further. From the official doc: `It was originally designed to display extensive traceback information in HTML for CGI scripts. It was later generalized to also display this information in plain text.`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using ipython:

```
import sys
from IPython.core.ultratb import ColorTB
print(''.join(ColorTB().structured_traceback(*sys.exc_info())))
```

Comment: I wanted to create a traceback handler for use within an asyncio loop. This produced a beautiful result, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point for colorizing (and otherwise formatting) text, you'll probably want to look at the [curses library](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html).  Also see [this how-to](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/curses/), which looks useful.

As for overriding Python's built-in error handling for all programs...I've never tried it, but I would think that would involve some fairly low-level changes.  You could always wrap your code in a huge try/except block, but I assume you don't want to do that.  I favor the more Unixy approach of writing a little script that does one thing, and does it well: have it take an input and, if it's a stack trace, colorize it.  Otherwise, pass the text through unchanged.  Using a pipe, like you suggested, may be the best way.  (In this case, to pipe stderr you'd want to do something like this, which merges stderr with stdout before piping: `cmd1 2>&1 | cmd2` )

Answer (score 0):

Also you can open traceback file with vim, using `:cfile` command. Then you can open highlighted ant interactive list of files in traceback using `:copen` command and jump between these files using set of related vim commands.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`better_exceptions`](https://github.com/Qix-/better-exceptions). This gives you colours and also much more detailed stack trace info. This is preferable to other libraries such as `colored-traceback` as it's still under active development. Copying over info from their README.

`pip install better_exceptions`

Set the BETTER_EXCEPTIONS environment variable to any value:

```bash
export BETTER_EXCEPTIONS=1  # Linux / OSX
setx BETTER_EXCEPTIONS 1    # Windows
```

and you're good to go!

Results in outputs like this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Load the text into vim:

```
nosetests | vim -
```

Set vim to highlight all lines that match a search

```
:set hlsearch
```

Search for lines with "your" path

```
/.*/path/to/my/code.*
```

Voila - all the lines with your path will be highlighted.

If you want to highlight the next line as well then you can do that too:

```
/.*/path/to/my/code.*\n.*
```